# query taking more time to execute

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

1. Query is taking around 5mins to 20 mins to execute.
2. Due to this we are getting load spikes.
3. Please help me to rewrite the query.
4. Also help me to improve the performance of query.

Query:

```
SELECT DATE(create_time) as createDate, count(url_id) 
  FROM t_notification 
 WHERE domain_id = 185 
   AND type = 12 
   AND create_time >= '2012-12-15' 
GROUP BY createDate
```

Explain

```
explain select DATE(create_time) as createDate, count(url_id) from t_notification where domain_id = 185 and type = 12 and create_time >= '2012-12-15' group by createDate;
    +----+-------------+----------------+------+---------------------------------+----------+---------+-------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
    | id | select_type | table          | type | possible_keys                   | key      | key_len | ref   | rows    | Extra                                        |
    +----+-------------+----------------+------+---------------------------------+----------+---------+-------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
    |  1 | SIMPLE      | t_notification | ref  | FK_notification_domain,idx_test | idx_test | 5       | const | 9189516 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
    +----+-------------+----------------+------+---------------------------------+----------+---------+-------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
    1 row in set (0.29 sec)

mysql> show create table t_notification\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: t_notification
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `t_notification` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `content` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
  `create_time` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `domain_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `url_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `targetrul_partnerurl_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `week_entrances` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'for keyword and target_url',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `url_id` (`url_id`),
  KEY `targetrul_partnerurl_id` (`targetrul_partnerurl_id`),
  KEY `FK_notification_domain` (`domain_id`,`id`),
  KEY `idx_test` (`domain_id`,`status`,`type`,`create_time`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=50747991 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 2):

From [MySQl docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html)

> Suppose that you issue the following SELECT statement:  mysql> SELECT
>   * FROM tbl_name WHERE col1=val1 AND col2=val2;
>
> If a multiple-column index exists on col1 and col2, the appropriate
>   rows can be fetched directly. If separate single-column indexes exist
>   on col1 and col2, the optimizer will attempt to use the Index Merge
>   optimization (see Section 8.3.1.4, “Index Merge Optimization”), or
>   attempt to find the most restrictive index by deciding which index
>   finds fewer rows and using that index to fetch the rows.
>
> If the table has a multiple-column index, any leftmost prefix of the
>   index can be used by the optimizer to find rows. For example, if you
>   have a three-column index on (col1, col2, col3), you have indexed
>   search capabilities on (col1), (col1, col2), and (col1, col2, col3).

You don't have an useable index on type or create_time. Either drop status from key idx_test or create a new index on (type, create_time) or on type and create_time separately.

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating composite index on **domain_id**  and **type** columns as they are directly used in where clause. It will definitely improve the performance of your query.